# Converting hundreds of pictures of naming style "frame_0000.jpg", "frame_0001.jpg" into an avi?

Tags: video, images, ffmpeg

I have all of these images as jpegs and I want to stream them into an AVI.  I am trying to use ffmpeg with the command noted [here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs) but I get an error "No such file or directory".

My exact command is (from the folder containing all of these files):

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i frame_%d.jpg view.avi
```

How do I do this?  Also, how can I do this for a specific range of images?  Say I only want frames 500 to 1000, so I want frame_0500.jpg to frame_1000.jpg?

Comment: If you were doing it one by one, does it work (thinking of a workaround)?

Comment: It might not be working because it is looking for frame_1, and you have frame_0001.

Comment: I think that is the reason, you're correct :) But there's no way I'm renaming thousands of files to remove those zeros.  There must be a way ffmpeg can handle this?

Comment: You can rename the files with [Bulk Renamer](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) but I don't think there is a way to do it without that

Comment: You can use `frame_%04d.jpg` to correctly handle the leading zeros but `ffmpeg` will still insist the sequence start at 0001. To start are 0500 I think you'll need to bulk rename.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct command should be

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i frame_%04d.jpg view.avi
```

The `%04d` means the number is 4 characters in length, zero padded (0000-9999).

If you want to do a range, I would just move the files you want into their own directory.

This is easy with a gui, but with command line you could do

```
mv frame_0[5-9]* newfolder
mv frame_1000* newfolder
```

Answer (score 7):

## glob pattern

For those of you using a non-ancient build of `ffmpeg` the glob pattern is the most flexible method:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

## sequence

This will convert a series of numbered inputs, `image-0001.png`, `image-0002.png`, etc:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30000/1001 -i image-%04d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mkv
```

- Add `-start_number`, such as `-start_number 100`, as an input option if you want to start with particular image.

## `cat`

You can also use `cat` to pipe your images to `ffmpeg`:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -framerate ntsc -f image2pipe -c:v mjpeg -i - -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

---

### Notes

- The output will use the same frame rate as the input. If you do not declare `-framerate` then the default of 25 will be used. You can also add `-r` as an output option, such as in `-r 25`, if you want `ffmpeg` to read the input at a certain rate, and then drop or duplicate frames to achieve a different output frame rate.
- Depending on your input, `ffmpeg` version, and selected encoder, `ffmpeg` will attempt to avoid or minimize chroma subsampling. Although this may be good in a technical sense it can produce an output that is not playable by non-FFmpeg based players. Adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` will ensure that your output is playable when encoding to H.264 video.
- It is recommended to use a recent build of `ffmpeg` since development is so active and to avoid bugs that have already been fixed. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Windows, OS X, and Linux.

### Also see

- [image2 demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for additional information, options, and examples.
- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for help on getting a good quality output.
- [FFmpeg slideshow from images - only one frame shown](https://superuser.com/a/714214/110524) for potential common issues and how to resolve them.