# FFMPEG slideshow from images - only one frame shown

Tags: ffmpeg, slideshow

I am a beginner with ffmpeg.

I want to convert several images to a slideshow and came up with this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i *.jpg -r 25 output.mp4
```

Pretty straight forward. However, the video seems like only one frame long (it is too fast to recognize for me)

Here is the Ouput of the above command:

```
    ffmpeg version 0.8.9-4:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  9 2013 19:12:07 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, image2, from 'swirl3777.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 1600x1200 [PAR 72:72 DAR 4:3], 0.20 tbr, 0.20 tbn, 0.20 tbc
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj444p' for codec 'mjpeg', auto-selecting format 'yuvj420p'
[buffer @ 0x86e2040] w:1600 h:1200 pixfmt:yuvj444p
[avsink @ 0x86e8920] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x86e8d80] w:1600 h:1200 fmt:yuvj444p -> w:1600 h:1200 fmt:yuvj420p flags:0x4
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj444p' for codec 'mjpeg', auto-selecting format 'yuvj420p'
[buffer @ 0x86e8c00] w:1600 h:1200 pixfmt:yuvj444p
[avsink @ 0x87159a0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x86f1860] w:1600 h:1200 fmt:yuvj444p -> w:1600 h:1200 fmt:yuvj420p flags:0x4
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj444p' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x86f17c0] w:1600 h:1200 pixfmt:yuvj444p
[avsink @ 0x870f4a0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x8737e60] w:1600 h:1200 fmt:yuvj444p -> w:1600 h:1200 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Output #0, image2, to 'swirl3786.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1600x1200 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 0.20 tbc
Output #1, image2, to 'swirl3787.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #1.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1600x1200 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 0.20 tbc
Output #2, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #2.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1600x1200 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #1.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #2.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=10.2 Lq=10.2 q=9.5 size=      -0kB time=0.04 bitrate=  -4.4kbits/s    
video:584kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.003680%
```

I also tried avconv but it's the same output, even the same file size.
If I change the -r values to something ridiculous like 3434321 it still get the same file size. If I add -b 512k oder -b 1024 it still get the same file size again...
It seems like, the options get ignored in some way.

The three pictures in the folder are detected correctly.

Is there any issues with the incompatible pixel format?

I am here on Ubuntu 12.04 ffmpeg version 0.8.9-4:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Any guess, what I could have done wrong here? TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Glob

`ffmpeg` from FFmpeg supports [glob patterns](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2), so your input files can be named almost anything as long as they are in the order you want:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4
```

Ubuntu uses `avconv` and the buggy, fake "`ffmpeg`" from Libav, a fork of FFmpeg, and these do not support glob patterns. See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)

## Get `ffmpeg`

To get `ffmpeg`, you can simply [download a Linux build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) or follow a [step-by-step guide to compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

---

## Potential Issues

### First image is skipped

There are some unresolved issues or inconsistencies involving `-r` and the [`fps` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps). Sometimes the first input image appears to be skipped or displayed for only a frame. You can use the `fps` filter to avoid the skipping issue as shown in my example above. See tickets [#1578](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1578) and [#3164](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3164) for more info.

### Last image is skipped

It may appear that the last image is skipped or displayed for one frame. I did not find an elegant solution to this behavior, but you can simply make a copy of the last image file to compensate.

### Even more skipping

If your input images are not all the same pixel format and/or frame size then `ffmpeg` may skip an indeterminate number of frames. Make sure all input images are similar to avoid this. You can see the console output which will mention any input file differences.

### The output MP4 video does not play

Use a less crappy player, or use the `format` filter as shown in my example, or use the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` output option. Otherwise `ffmpeg` will attempt to avoid or minimize [chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) (depending on your input, the encoder you're using, your `ffmpeg` version, and the encoding options you use), and although this may be good in a technical sense, it can create an output that is not playable by non-FFmpeg based players.

Comment: Thank you! ffmpeg on Ubuntu is really buggy, didn't expect that. I followed your posted step-by-step guide. Took a while on this old system (and installed nasm, not yasm!) but it works partly now. The first image is only shown one frame when I use -r but not the last image. When I use the fps video filter the last image is skipped. I will maybe do a workaround with an empty image or double the last image. Again thank you for your well organized post - Pointed me in the right direction and the Potential Issues list was great!

Comment: I didn't know ubuntu may cause issues. i was testing command on ubuntu for last two weeks. And noticed it skipped last image(s)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2 -r 1/5 -i img%03d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 output.mp4
```

Your jpegs have to be numbered sequentially in the format img001.jpg...img009.jpg. The `%03d` stands for a 3 digit sequence- 2 leading zeroes to start with. If you had img01.jpg to img 09.jpg you would use `img%02d.jpg`. The `*.jpg` syntax will not work.